# Multiple Date Ranges Different Rows - Exclusion Logic

Tags: sql-server

I need to find Customer transaction that didn't occur while a customer was considered a "premium customer". In this example, the sql retrieves row #2. How do I avoid retrieving any records since this customer was a premium on purchase date as referenced in row 1.

```
SELECT 
FROM TblPremCus c INNER JOIN tblTrans t ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
WHERE t.PurchaseDate NOT BETWEEN c.StartDate AND c.EndDate
```

Data:

```
**tblPremCus**
ROWID   CustomerID  StartDate   EndDate
 1       ABC123     1/1/2016    6/16/2016
 2       ABC123     9/3/2016    12/21/9999
```

---

```
**tblTrans**
TransID   CustomerID  PurchaseDate
T1           ABC123       6/1/16
```

Expected Result: NONE

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to get all transactions where the transaction date does not fall in between the dates that customer is 'premium'.

In a case like this, though, it is easier to find transactions that DO fall into one of those ranges, and is a simple change from what you started with:

```
SELECT * FROM TblPremCus c 
INNER JOIN tblTrans t ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID 
WHERE t.PurchaseDate BETWEEN c.StartDate AND c.EndDate
```

We've seen that using `NOT BETWEEN` is not good enough to weed out unwanted transactions, but now that we know which transactions we DON'T want, we can find the ones we DO: simply, any ones not returned by the above query.

```
SELECT * from TblTrans 
WHERE TransID NOT IN (SELECT TransID FROM TblPremCus c 
  INNER JOIN tblTrans t ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID 
  WHERE t.PurchaseDate BETWEEN c.StartDate AND c.EndDate)
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation surrounding code as that makes the answer much more useful.

Comment: agreed, and changed. hopefully a bit better, at least